# Determine axes of calling event in matplotb

Tags: python, matplotlib

This must be answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find anything. Anyway...

I have two events and handlers:

1. The first responds to clicks on an image canvas, and draws the point on the image.
2. The second responds to button clicks and runs some code.

My issue is that the `onclick` function which is registered to the `'button_press_event`' fires for both clicks on the image axes and clicks on the button axes. For example, the code below, will print and draw points on the image axes (using coordinates from the button axes) when the button is clicked. These appear in the top-left of the image axes.

Is there a way to determine the axes of calling event so that `onclick` **is not** called when the button is clicked, but **is** called when the image axes is clicked?

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.imshow(np.random.rand(512,512), cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.set_xlim(0,512)
ax.set_ylim(512,0)

buttonax = plt.axes([0.8,0.025,0.1,0.04])
button = Button(buttonax, 'click')

def onclick(event):
    x,y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print x,y
    # plot the points
    ax.plot(x, y, 'or', ms=7)
    plt.draw()

def button_func(event):
    print "button is clicked"

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
button.on_clicked(button_func)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib events store an `inaxes` attribute that is the parent `Axes` instance the event occurred in or `None` if the event was not over an axes.

In your case, you'd want to check something similar to:

```
if event.inaxes is ax:
    ...
```

There's one caveat to this: If you have overlapping axes (e.g. an inset axes or anything involving `twinx`/`twiny`), only the upper axes will respond to the event ("upper" in terms of zorder, if I recall correctly).  You won't get a list of all axes the event is over or multiple callbacks if it's over more than one axes.

Comment: I was inspecting the attributes of `event.inaxes` object, not realizing it was `event.inaxes` itself that I needed. Thanks!